# how to insert multuple row to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

i have a upload result form for a certain semester. where i have collected all the subjects and student list for a certain semester.but my problem is i can't insert the result to the database.only a single row is inserted,

controller

```
    $data=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['Number']);$i++){
            if($_POST['Number'][$i] != ''){
                $data=array(
                        'Id'=>$_POST['id'][$i],
                        'Dept'=>$_POST['Dept'][$i],
                        'SubjectCode'=>$_POST['sCode'][$i],
                        'SubjectName'=>$_POST['sName'][$i],
                        'Semister'=>$_POST['Semister'][$i],
                        'MidNumber'=>$_POST['Number'][$i]
                        );
                $this->load->model('Upload_Result_model');
                $this->Upload_Result_model->upload_midResult($data);
            }
    }
```

form:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Student ID</th>
    <?php foreach($subjects as $s):?>
    <th><?php echo $s->subjectName;   echo "<br>";   echo "(".$s->subjectCode.")"; ?></th>
    <?php foreach($student as $st):?>
    <input type='hidden' id='id[]' name='id[]' value='<?php echo $st->Id;?>'>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <input type='hidden' name='Dept[]' id='Dept[]' value=<?php echo $Dept;?>>
    <input type='hidden' name='Semister[]' id='Semister[]' value=<?php echo $Semister;?>>
    <input type='hidden' id='sCode[]' name='sCode[]' value='<?php echo $s->subjectCode?>'>
    <input type='hidden' id='sName[]' name='sName[]' value='<?php echo $s->subjectName?>'>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tr>
<?php foreach($student as $st):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $st->Id?></td>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($subjects);$i++):?>
    <td><input type='text' size='7' id='Number[]' name='Number[]'/></td>
    <?php endfor;?>
</tr>
```

it will be very much helpful for me if anyone fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

i dont think the html form elements will come in as arrays in php. try doing `print_r($_POST);` to see the passed variables and their values. they might come in just comma separates.

i think you might need to do something like `$_POST['id']=explode(',',$_POST['id']);` and so on to fix your problem

the `Numbers` variable also has other problems you should look in to

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
    foreach($student as $st):
```

should be after the . Now you open multiple rows, but not closing them. Also Ids are inside 2 for loops, so they are more than the other elements, I am not sure if this is what you try to do.

So, if this is ok you can try:

```
    $Numbers = @$_POST['Number'];
    $ids = @$_POST['id'];

    foreach($Numbers as $a => $b)
    {
      if($Numbers[$a]!='')
      { 
         $data=array(
                    'Id'=>$ids[$a];, ... }
      }
    }
```